# UI Router not routing

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have an index.html file in the parent dir and with `http://localhost:3000/#/` that's what's being loaded instead of the sidebar.html file. If I try `http://localhost:300/#/home` it redirects to todo

No errors being thrown.

app.js

```
'use strict';

angular
  .module('App', [
    'ui.router'
    //'lbServices'
  ])

  .run([ '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
      $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }])

  .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

      .state('home', {
        title: 'Dashboard',
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '../shared/sidebar/sidebar.html',
        controller: 'sidebarCtrl'
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('todo');
  }]);
```

server.js

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

// Set up the /favicon.ico
app.use(loopback.favicon());

// request pre-processing middleware
app.use(loopback.compress());

// -- Add your pre-processing middleware here --

// boot scripts mount components like REST API
boot(app, __dirname);

// -- Mount static files here--
// All static middleware should be registered at the end, as all requests
// passing the static middleware are hitting the file system
// Example:
   var path = require('path');
   app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
   app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')));

// Requests that get this far won't be handled
// by any middleware. Convert them into a 404 error
// that will be handled later down the chain.
app.use(loopback.urlNotFound());

// The ultimate error handler.
app.use(loopback.errorHandler());

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
  });
};

// start the server if `$ node server.js`
if (require.main === module) {
  app.start();
}
```

Not sure if this is related, but initially my server was set to listen on 0.0.0.0:3000 but if I typed that into the URL bar it went to Google search. Although if I type localhost:3000 it seemed to work. I have since changed the listening port to localhost:3000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, that this url `http://localhost:3000/#/`, which should trigger state home - is loading `index.html` - should mean, that the path

```
templateUrl: '../shared/sidebar/sidebar.html',
```

is not set properly. Use the (e.g. *chrome*) developer tools and check if the `sidebar.html` is being loaded.

The fact that this url `http://localhost:300/#/home` is navigating to TODO state is also correct, becuase `'/home'` is not mapped to `home` state

```
.state('home', {
    ...
    url: '/',
  });
```

so the default is triggered

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('todo');
```

*NOTE: From the question, and described issue I expect that the `index.html` is set properly. It contains `<div ui-view=""></div>`, which will be filled with `sidebar.html`. That's why I would suspect the wrong path to that partial view template...*

Comment: The problem was my misunderstanding of how index.html serves as the foundation for everything else. I was trying to get sidebar.html to load instead of index.html to do some POC stuff. Your answer helped me realize that.

Comment: Great to see that, really. Enjoy might UI-Router ;) good luck